# Debug Custom Resolver in SDL Web 8+

Tags: web8, publishing

I am working on a Custom Resolver and in the past (2013 SP1 HR1) I have been able to debug it in Visual Studio using Attach to Process on TcmPublisher.exe and dllhost.exe at the same time.

Has anyone done this in Web 8.1.1 or 8.5?  What processes can I attach to?

Answer (score 5):

You can use Process Monitor, see here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx to search by your DLL name, e.g. MyCustomResolver.dll, and it will tell you which process is running that DLL. So just like in 2013 SP1 you can attach and debug it.

Answer (score 5):

Resolvers are normally executed by the Publisher Service (`TcmPublisher.exe`) or by the Core Service (either `TcmServiceHost.exe` or `w3wp.exe`).

They can also be executed by the SDL Web COM+ application (`dllhost.exe` or `dllhst3g.exe`) if you are using the Legacy Pack.